# access denied finding property net.dns1 photo capture using camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

While opening the camera to capture the image programmatically, I'm facing below error

```
access denied finding property net.dns1.

access denied finding property net.dns2.

access denied finding property net.dns3.
```

image able to capture, while clicking on saving the captured image throwing above exception and app closed.

what could be the reason?

Comment: Share your code